# Why does the cascode current mirror have a lower output capacitance?

Tags: analog

[image]

Fig 1

[image]

Fig 2

Comparing Fig 1, a normal current mirror, with Fig 2, a cascode current mirror, why is the output capacitance at the drain of Q3 in Fig 2 lower than that at the drain of Q2 in Fig 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The effective capacitance as seen at the drain of Q2 is enhanced by the Miller effect. A positive voltage transient applied to the drain induces an increase in gate voltage (since the transient is conducted through Cgd), which induces an increase in drain current--the effective capacitance is thus increased.

In the cascode arrangement, Q3 acts to isolate Q2's drain from voltage transients at the output. A transient applied to Q3's drain would result in only a tiny voltage transient at Q2's drain (since the Q2 drain voltage is effectively regulated to stay one Vgs drop below the constant voltage applied to Q3 gate). Another way to look at this is that Q3 acts as a current buffer--Q2 outputs a constant current and Q3 buffers it to be resilient to output voltage transients. Because a transient voltage applied to the output no longer leads to a significant transient current, the effective output capacitance is reduced.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, in Fig 2, there is Cgd for Q3. Would this Cgs for Q3 also be enhanced by the Miller effect? Also would the output capacitance  be reduced if Q2 is cascoded by (1) a diode-connected nmos; (2) a diode-connected pmos; (3) a resistor? Out of these three options, which would reduce the output capacitance by the most extent?

Comment: Excuse me. I would like to confirm one thing. In Fig 2, do you refer to the drain of Q2 or the drain of Q3 as the output port? Do you mean the cascode arrangement reduces the capacitance seen at the drain of Q2 instead of the drain of Q3? Thanks.

Comment: No, Q3 drain is the output port. Obviously, because (to misquote the famous bank robber) that's where the voltage is.  And no again. Q3 drain capacitance is reduced because charge passing  through Cgd doesn't affect Q3 gate, so it isn't amplified. Today's question will probably be why doesn't it affect Q3 gate? Because that is connected to a very low (AC) impedance.

Comment: @PhaeLeung Q3 drain is the output port. As for "Also would the output capacitance be reduced if Q2 is cascoded by (1) a diode-connected nmos; (2) a diode-connected pmos; (3) a resistor? Out of these three options, which would reduce the output capacitance by the most extent?" -- you may want to simulate these yourself to see. I don't have an immediate answer off the top of my head.